# Change pitch of mp3 audio on a microcontroller

Tags: audio, mp3

I have an MP3 decoder running on a ESP32, and I'd like to change the pitch of the streaming audio in real time.

I plan to build a little toy that streams Amazon Alexa and changes her voice so that it is higher pitched. So no pro audio requirements at all, it is just supposed to be a funny effect.

I was thinking maybe I can operate on the raw DCT data? Or is there another way that is fast enough for that chip? I cannot use time compression/dilation because the audio is streamed.

I'm using the MAD fixed point decoder.

A description of (or a link to) an algorithm working on DCT or PCM data would be fine, but code or pseudo-code in whatever language would be very welcome.

Comment: Are you wishing to preserve harmonic relationships between points in the spectrum or just shift up or down the whole lot by x?

Comment: explaining why Andy aka is asking: **shifting** in the frequency domain (i.e. adding an offset) can be done very easily by mixing with a sinusoidal (but that doesn't preserve the harmonic relationships). **Compressing/streching** the frequency domain would preserve harmonic relationships but takes much more effort (FFT and IFFT) .

Comment: I have a hard time answering that question because I don't really understand the differences or drawbacks. 
I suspect doing an FFT/IFFT would be too expensive, and basically I just want it to sound funny - if theres some distortion, thats ok.

Comment: @MichaelBöckling to help you answer that question: Could you simply **edit** your original question to explain to what *end* / for what *purpose* you want to do this?

Comment: You're right, just did that.

Comment: Your description of the device and the of plan you have are way too vague. What do you expect from us? Reverse-engineer the whole existing firmware and add the hack you request? Or modify the hardware by inserting "stuff" between the output of your device and the speakers to have the requested effect?

Comment: Clarified what I wanted. Of course I'm not looking for someone to code something up for me, but surely there must be well known techniques to do such a thing, and all I'd like is pointer into the right direction.

Comment: Maybe. I think you can flag your own post for mod attention if you want to proceed wiht this. Anyway, it wasn't very clear at first that you alredy developed the firmware yourself based on some open-source decoder. Now, I'm not sure what I'm saying, but I believe the MP3 format is based on "levels" for each small frequency band across the whole spectrum. If it's really like that, you can maybe just hack MAD a bit, so that these levels are shifted a bit to the higher frequencies, before reconstructing the output waveform.

Comment: You could be right, I've found this as a starting point: http://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/pitch-shifting-using-the-ft/
I'll report back in case it works.

Thanks for the "flag" hint, I had searched for something like this but missed it.

Comment: [Here](http://yehar.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/deip.pdf) is a great resource about piece-wise polynomial interpolators. The answer really depends on the capabilities of the MCU in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "phase vocoder" which will use short term FFT properties to change the pitch without changing the duration.

There is plenty of information and links to "phase vocoder" on Wikipedia and Google in general.

It is a great educational exercise to go through its operation as you learn from it the critical importance of the phase information in the FFT for proper reconstruction.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, I guess, to change your MP3's pitch is to actually play them at a different sampling rate that the header (bits 21 & 22) specifies – that will of course change the overall duration of playback.

Comment: This might work if I just wanted to slow down, but I wanted to pitch it up and since its streaming audio (though with limited length) and I can't buffer everything I'm not sure that'll work out. But I'll try that first, just in case my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: why only to slow down? If you fake a higher sampling rate than what was used, tones should be higher!

Comment: I tried halving the sample rate and started to stream web radio, then the server drops the connection because I read data too slow. If I double the sample rate instead, will I not get buffer underruns because samples will be consumed faster than they come in?

Comment: @MichaelBöckling aah I forgot about the streaming aspect; well, then things get more haiy :/